# FORMULARIOS CON PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, poo

A través de un formulario, definir un objeto de la clase `Persona` y llamar a sus métodos.crear un objeto de la clase `Empleado` y llamar a sus métodos. Almacenar la información en una base de datos.

```
<form action="methods.php" method="post">
    Nombre : <input type="text" name="nombre" /><br />
    Genero:  <input type="text" name="genero" /><br />
    Edad:  <input type="number" name="edad" /><br />
    Sueldo:  <input type="number" name="sueldo" /><br />
    Tipo de contrato:  <input type="text" name="tipoContrato" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="¡Enviarme!" />
</form>
```

Y este es mi codigo php, Los resultados de momento los tengo estáticos pero quiero enviarlos mediante el formulario
Agradezco mucho su respuestas me serian de gran ayuda!!!

```
<?php

class Persona
{
    public $nombre;
    public $genero;
    public $edad;

    public function __construct($nombre, $genero, $edad)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->genero = $genero;
        $this->edad   = $edad;
    }

    public function imprimeDatos()
    {
        return "Mi nombre es: {$this->nombre}, mi género es {$this->genero} y mi edad es: {$this->edad}";
    }

}

class Empleado extends Persona
{
    public function __construct($nombre, $genero, $edad, $sueldo, $tipoContrato)
    {
        parent::__construct($nombre, $genero, $edad);
        $this->sueldo = $sueldo;
        $this->tipoContrato = $tipoContrato;
    }

    public function cargaSueldo()
    {
        return "Tu sueldo ahora será de: $".$this->sueldo = $this->sueldo + 20;
    }

    public function tipoContrato()
    {
        return "Tu tipo de contrato es: {$this->tipoContrato}";
    }
}
$empleadoRoberto = new Empleado("Roberto", "Masculino", 23, 3500, "de por vida");
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $empleadoRoberto->imprimeDatos();
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $empleadoRoberto->cargaSueldo();
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $empleadoRoberto->tipoContrato();
```

Comment: Esto parece a todas luces un ejercicio. Entonces, lo que se te pide es que recojas lo datos en el formulario y luego los mandes a procesar en el servidor. Debes recoger los datos que enviaste mediante POST, haciendo algo así: `$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];` (y los demás datos). Luego creas una instancia de la clase y le pasas los datos que recogiste: `$mPersona=new Persona ($nombre, ...);` Más o menos eso. El anunciado es confuso: *definir un objeto de la clase Persona y llamar a sus métodos.crear un objeto de la clase Empleado y llamar a sus métodos* dado que `Empleado` extiende de `Persona` ...

Comment: ... se podría hacer con una simple instancia de `Empleado`, pero bueno, no sé si te explicaron con claridad lo que se requiere. En el código, no sé a que viene esto por ejemplo: `$empleadoRoberto = new Empleado("Roberto", "Masculino", 23, 3500, "de por vida");` ¿por qué pasas los datos a mano? ¿acaso el formulario no era para recoger los datos?